# Powershell remove text from string

Tags: powershell

I have a string

`[Test: ABC.Test (6)] MORETEXTGOESHERE [(null)] <(null)> - A red fox jumped the fence`

and would like to trim the string to only show

`A red fox jumped the fence`

What is the best way to go about it. I'm sure I'll manage with SubStrings and IndexOfs but perhaps some regex expression could do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

Using substring you can do this:

```
PS> $str = '[Test: ABC.Test (6)] MORETEXTGOESHERE [(null)] <(null)> - ' +`
           'A red fox jumped the fence'
PS> $str.Substring($str.LastIndexOf('-')+2)
A red fox jumped the fence
```

That's a bit brittle if processing a line with no `-` characters.  Here's a regex that would work:

```
PS> $str | Select-String '-\s*([^-]*)$' | Foreach{$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}
A red fox jumped the fence
```

And if processing line by line, I like this approach:

```
PS> if ($str -match '-\s*([^-]*)$') { $matches[1] }
A red fox jumped the fence
```

And with the more realistic string:

```
PS> $str = '2010-09-09 07:15:31,749 [ABC: TEST.TEST (3)] ABB MYCLASS.TEST ' +`
           '[(null)] <(null)> - MessageId: ' +`
           '46b8fd3c-9ce8-4699-9d1b-91f31bfb5c62 CREATED'
PS> if ($str -match '- MessageId:\s*(.*)$') { $matches[1] }
46b8fd3c-9ce8-4699-9d1b-91f31bfb5c62 CREATED
```

or if you don't want CREATED in the output:

```
PS> if ($str -match '- MessageId:\s*(.*?)\s+CREATED\s*$') { $matches[1] }
46b8fd3c-9ce8-4699-9d1b-91f31bfb5c62
```

Comment: Hmm.. perhaps I didnt paint the full picture, sorry.

Comment: Here's a more real life example
2010-09-09 07:15:31,749 [ABC: TEST.TEST (3)] ABB MYCLASS.TEST [(null)] <(null)> - MessageId: 46b8fd3c-9ce8-4699-9d1b-91f31bfb5c62 CREATED

Comment: Do you want to extract everything from MessageId to the end or do you want to leave out 'CREATED'?

Answer (score 1):

If your string has a fixed pattern...i.e. the text you are interested is always after <(null)>, and there is no ">" in the text, then how about splitting the input line on ">" and getting the 2nd element of the array returned.